Found project reference without a matching metadata reference
Starting with .NET 9 I have a Solution containing a Blazor webapp, a couple of .NET 9 class libraries and ONE class library in .NET Standard 2.0 with only 2 entities.
When I run the Blazor project with dotnet watch, I get a warning coming from the .NET Standard library:

dotnet watch ⚠ msbuild: [Warning] Found project reference without a matching metadata reference: D:\DEV\Microgate\Microgate.Projects\src\Microgate.Projects.Contracts\Microgate.Projects.Contracts.csproj

The .csproj is very simple:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

And it has NO references at all:

Any advice on how to remove the annoying warning? Before upgrading to .NET 9, I didn't have this...


Can you please share a [mre]?

here you are
https://github.com/SandroRiz/ProjectReferenceWithoutMatching
Run dotnet watch and see the yellow warning

The same occurs if the Classlibrary is netstandard2.1
